# Is it possible to Change the NullType for Null values in Dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

I have few attributes in an item which are not PK/SK/GSI but null. So when I store then in Dynamo DB it shows them as Null with Type as Null. Is there any way where I can change the type from Null to String/Boolean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a data type without updating each item you want to change one-by-one.

DynamoDB has a [Null](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#API_AttributeValue_Contents) data type, but it's best to drop null values and not store them at all.

In short, to overcome your issue you'll have to make a change on how you write items.

Comment: Does dyanmo by default take Null type for null values ?

Comment: Yes, null will become Null. A simple condition on the client side can either drop null or convert to boolean.